# Foreach in Multi-Dimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array, foreach

I'm trying to practice/learn *foreach* loops in PHP. I understand basic foreach. But I struggle with multi-dimensionals.

I have an array to test it out:

```
$data = array(
        array('New York', 'New York City'),
        array('hotel', 'lodging','motel'),
        array('cheap')
    );
```

What I would like to do is loop through each and fine every possible combination & assign it to it's own array (will later be displayed as columns).

```
First column ('New York', 'New York City')
second column ('New York hotel', 'New York lodging', 'New York motel')
third column ('New York City hotel', 'New York City lodging', 'New York City motel')
fourth column ('New York hotel cheap', 'New York lodging cheap', 'New York motel cheap')
fifth column ('New York City hotel cheap', 'New York City lodging cheap', 'New York City motel cheap')
```

How would I accomplish this? I've tried a couple things, but haven't even gotten close.

**Update**
My end goal is to have an individual be able to take a list of items, and try to find all possible keywords. This will then help in identifying different SEO keywords that they can consider using.
So sometimes the Data array may have 2 sub arrays, other times it may have 3 or 4. So it would need to be a bit dynamic.

**1st Solution Attempt**

```
public function recurseful($start, $args)
{
    if (is_array($args))
        {
            foreach ($args[0] as $value)
            {
                $this->output[] = trim("{$start} {$value}");
                if (count($args) > 1)
                {
                    $this->recurseful($value, array_slice($args, 1));
                }

            }
        }
    return;
}
```

However, this returns all of my words in a single array. That does not meet the requirements of what I'm looking for.

Comment: If you elaborated a little more on your input and expected output it might be easier for us to establish the pattern.

Comment: I've updated. does that help make it more clear what I'm wanting to accomplish?

Comment: Not really mate - try show an actual test-case with your "SEO" words with say 3 arrays in $data and then the desired output - otherwise it's unclear what the relationship between them is.

Comment: I've updated per your request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright. After several more hours & a lot of collaboration at work: here it is:

```
function permutate($data, $limit){
    $this->limit = $limit;
    $this->data = $data;
    $this->numLevels = count($this->data);

    $this->possiblePermutations = 1;
    foreach ($this->data as $array){
        $this->possiblePermutations *= count($array);
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i < $this->numLevels - 0; $i++){
        $this->permutations[$i] = array();
    }

    $this->recurse(0, 0, '');

    return $this->permutations;
}

private function recurse($currentLevel, $level, $string){
    if ($this->numPerms == $this->limit) 
        return;

    foreach ($this->data[$level] as $val){
        if ($this->numPerms == $this->limit) 
            return;

        $newString = "$string $val";
        if ($level == $currentLevel){
            $this->permutations[$level][] = trim($newString);
            $this->numPerms++;
        }

        if ($level < $this->numLevels - 1 AND $level <= $currentLevel){
            $this->recurse($currentLevel, $level + 1, $newString);
        }
    }

    if (! $level AND $currentLevel < $this->numLevels){
        $this->recurse($currentLevel + 1, 0, '');
    }
}
```

I changed some of the variables names, etc. But this works wonderfully!

Comment: While it's perfectly okay to *answer and accept* to your own question - this partial code block isn't actually useful to anyone else in its current state as it's clearly part of a larger class.  You should refine your answer to match the simplified nature of your original question in such a way that a straight forward copy/paste will demonstrate a working example.  Please also then consider accepting the answer to close the topic.

Comment: I see what you're saying. Figured the class part was just a wrapper in this case. The rest of the code would be over in my controller. So the functions themselves are able to be copy/pasted. Wouldn't that suffice? I'm obviously a bit newer to Stack Overflow, so some of the accepted practices I'm not aware of. So let me know.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is create a function that will do this for you, recursively, something like....

```
// function for building recursive tree arrays
function recursive($array) {
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        if(is_array($value)) {
            // if it is an array, it will run again
            recursive($value);
        } else {
            // do something with values here
        }
    }
    // return your result set here
}

$data = array(
        array('key', 'key2'),
        array('word', 'word2','word3'),
        array(array('more','levels','than','you','need'), 'then','some','more')
    );

$result = recursive($data);
```

It's rough, but depending on what you're doing, you simply need to add your process to get out your total final result.

Basically, it will just keep running regardless of how many depths your array is, or the sequence of the array structure. All you need to do is ensure you are sending (returning) the results back of each sweep of the function, this will depend on what you do with each level.

It should get you well on your way though.

Comment: I have followed something similar to what you have. But this returns everything into a single array, instead of multiple arrays. I'm sure this would be a simple adjustment. What do you suggest based on the code I added to my first question?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here's a non-recursive solution which I believe follows the desired pattern as long as your `$data` array remains two-dimensional.  I'm not going to admit to how many attempts this actually took me...

```
$cols = array(array_shift($data));
while($row = array_shift($data))
  array_walk(count($cols)<=1 ? $cols : array_slice($cols, 1), 
  function($col) use($row, &$cols){
    foreach($col as $i => $prev)
      foreach($row as $j => $word)
          $tmp[count($cols)===1?$i:$j][] = "$prev $word";
    foreach($tmp as $t) $cols[] = $t;
  });
```

[run code](http://ideone.com/NxWcNj) <sup>**PHP 5.4 +*</sup>

---

Slightly off topic but worth mentioning - I don't know what context you are putting these "keywords" into but spamming them like this will likely constitute bad SEO.

Comment: Thanks. However, the array will most certainly not remain 2-dimensional. I put it that way to make it more simple to explain what is going on. ha. But I'll play around with what you have and see if I can expand on it a bit.

Comment: And you're right about SEO spam. This is to help generate a list of possible keywords. And then I'd go out to Adwords tool and see which ones are fruitful. This way I can easily look at an area and identify key words that pertain to the area, and easily create a large list of targeted keywords. (not sure if that makes sense).